# How do I unpack a binary string in PHP?

Tags: php, unpack, pack

How can I do this Perl code in PHP?

```
 print unpack ("H*", pack ("B*", "00000000100000012000000" ));
```

Comment: PHP's `pack` implementation appears to lack `B*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since pack/unpack in PHP doesn't support the B type, you'll have to use PHP's other functions instead.  In this case, [`dechex`](http://php.net/dechex) and [`bindec`](http://php.net/bindec).

```
echo dechex( bindec( "00000000100000012000000" ));
```

Edit: Or do it in a single function with base_convert:

```
echo base_convert("00000000100000012000000", 2, 16);
```

Comment: also got a diferent answer from devshed

http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/perl-unpack-pack-to-php-697140.html

Comment: I realise this is an old question, but I believe this is limited to 32bit or maybe 64 bit strings. Is there a way to do this for a arbitrary large string? and is there a reverse process?